# How to improve this regression neural network model in R and add accuracy as a metrics?

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying out neural network from caret package. In my current project I want to create a neural network which can solve a continuous function. Here I am solving this equation $y=\frac{sin(x^{2})}{2 x}$ . I coded the equation and its working fine except one warning.

```
library(caret)
equ<-function(x){
  v=sin(x^2)/2*x  
  return(v)
}

X=(1:50)
Y=equ(X)
I=cbind(X,Y)
I=data.frame(I)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number=10, verboseIter = TRUE, savePred=T)
model <- train(Y~X, data=I, method ="nnet", trControl = ctrl,verbose = TRUE)

print(model)
```

Now what can I do to improve this neural network model further? currently after training the model returns metrics in RMSE. I know for regression RMSE is used and for binary classification accuracy is used. But the biggest problem for me with RMSE is that it dosent tell me how good is my model. For example RMSE 0.0001 means nothing unless otherwise if I compare it with another models RMSE. But accuracy gives an absolute idea how good is our model eg 93%. Is there  a way to add accuracy to my model?